# Noun replacement: Shortlisting a costlier candidate as a placeholder to reject later?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English, for the act, where a recruiter shortlists a better candidate as a placeholder to please the Client, only to later reject him and hire a cheaper candidate?

Comment: Your question is puzzling to me, because it suggests that the recruiter is doing the hiring.  It's the client who does the hiring.

Comment: People do this? Who  pays the newly employed personnel, the recruiter or the employer?

Comment: perhaps this question should be asked at [The WorkPlace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) or [Law](http://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There's no sentence showing how this word would be used..

Comment: In my experience recruiters often come to the table with a few prospects for you to browse through as samples of the "type" of people they can get. Ideally, you like the prospects, and send the recruiter off to find you people to look through. 

Perhaps a recruiter showed up with excellent prospects, and then when you sent them off to find you people to make your decision between, they weren't as nice of options. Claiming (rightfully or not) that the prospects have already been taken somewhere else, or possibly just withholding them for higher/better clients

Comment: @Mari-LouA They do. Consider this example. There is a city infrastructure construction project. There is a Client, lot of contractors and subcontractors and a Recruitment Agency. It is mandated that the Contractor recruits a capable Lead Manager who reports on the activities and progress of the project to the client and his cost is covered by the Contractor. So instead of hiring the costly over performer, the RA hires a substandard cheap alternative, so the expense is lesser for the contractor. In this case the Agency is trying to be friendly with the contractor but not the Client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **bait and switch** at [investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bait-switch.asp).

> Basically, it means to attract with something promising and then switching it with something inferior at some point.